# Бесконечное ожидание нескольких await, вызванных в цикле

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es7

index.js:

```
    import Messaging from './messaging.js';

    const messaging = new Messaging('messaging-people__human', 'messaging-people__message');

    (async () => {
        await messaging.prepareElements();
        console.log('Second');
        messaging.start();
    })();
```

messaging.js:

```
    class Messaging {
        constructor (elementClassName, messageClassName) {
            this.elementClassName = elementClassName;
            this.messageClassName = messageClassName;
            this.elements = [];
        }

        _getSvg (element) {
            const objects = element.querySelectorAll('object');
            const object = objects[objects.length - 1];

         return new Promise (resolve => object.addEventListener('load',  () => {
             resolve(object.contentDocument.querySelector('svg'));
         }));
        }

        async prepareElements () {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.${this.elementClassName}`);

            const prepareElement = async (element, i) => {
                let [mainSvg, messageSvg] = await Promise.all([this._getSvg(element), this._getSvg(element.querySelector(`.${this.messageClassName}`))]);
                this.elements.push({
                    id: i + 1,
                    nodes: {
                        main: element,
                        mainSvg: mainSvg,
                        messageSvg: messageSvg
                    },
                    isMessaging: false,
                    messagingInfo: {
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                 })
                 return {mainSvg, messageSvg};
            };

            // Если использовать один await, то скрипт работает нормально
            // await prepareElement(elements[0], 0);

            // А если в цикле, то не заканчивается никогда
            let i = 0;
            const elementsPrepared = [];
            for (let element of elements) {
                elementsPrepared.push(await prepareElement(element, i));
                i++;
            }

            console.log('First');
            return elementsPrepared;
        }

        start () {
            console.log('Third');
            console.dir(this.elements);
        }
    }

    export default Messaging;
```

При одном `await` выводятся сообщения 'First', 'Second' и 'Third' и `index.js` дожидается конца асинхронной функции, а если использовать несколько `await` внутри цикла, то скрипт не доходит даже до `console.log('First')`, уходит в бесконечное выполнение без каких-либо ошибок. Транспайлер `Babel`, сборка `Webpack`. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас `prepareElements`  и `prepareElement` не возвращают промисы.

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, добавил возврат значений, код по-прежнему не работает

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас проблема в том, что не срабатывает событие `load` у вашего `object`. Возможно, не грузится, возможно у уже загруженного `object` событие вызываться не будет.

Я не знаю логику вашего приложения, поэтому много посоветовать не могу.

Что могу посоветовать:

- Возможно, можно проверить если `object` уже загружен, получить `object.contentDocument.querySelector('svg')` и если он есть, то потом уже выполнять `resolve`.
- Также, возможно стоит добавить таймаут на ожидание загрузки.

Посмотрите сделанный мной пример. В нем некоторые `object` уже как бы загружены, на остальных симулируется успешная загрузка.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/614of2tg/1/).

```js
class Messaging {
  constructor(elementClassName, messageClassName) {
    this.elementClassName = elementClassName;
    this.messageClassName = messageClassName;
    this.elements = [];
  }

  _getSvg(element) {
    const objects = element.querySelectorAll('object');
    const object = objects[objects.length - 1];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Если object уже загружен
      var svg = object.querySelector('svg');
      if (svg) {
        resolve(svg);
        return;
      }
      var timerId = setTimeout(() => reject("timeout"), 5000);
      // симулируем успешную загрузку
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        resolve(object);
      }, 2000);
      object.addEventListener('load', () => {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        resolve(object.contentDocument.querySelector('svg'));
      });
      object.addEventListener('error', () => { // This event doesn't work
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        reject("Load error");
      });
    });
  }

  async prepareElements() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.${this.elementClassName}`);

    const prepareElement = async(element, i) => {

      let [mainSvg, messageSvg] = await Promise.all([this._getSvg(element), this._getSvg(element.querySelector(`.${this.messageClassName}`))]);
      this.elements.push({
        id: i + 1,
        nodes: {
          main: element,
          mainSvg: mainSvg,
          messageSvg: messageSvg
        },
        isMessaging: false,
        messagingInfo: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      })
      return {
        mainSvg,
        messageSvg
      };
    };

    // Если использовать один await, то скрипт работает нормально
    // await prepareElement(elements[0], 0);

    // А если в цикле, то не заканчивается никогда
    let i = 0;
    const elementsPrepared = [];
    for (let element of elements) {
      elementsPrepared.push(await prepareElement(element, i));
      i++;
    }

    console.log('First');
    return elementsPrepared;
  }

  start() {
    console.log('Third');
    console.dir(this.elements);
  }
}
const mess = new Messaging('messaging-people__human', 'messaging-people__message');

(async() => {
  try {
    await mess.prepareElements();
    console.log('Second');
    mess.start();
  } catch (ex) { // Перехватываем ошибки
    console.error(ex);
  }
})()
```

```html
<div class="messaging-people__human">
  <object></object>
  <div class="messaging-people__message">
    <object>
      <svg></svg>
    </object>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="messaging-people__human">
  <object>
    <svg></svg>
  </object>
  <div class="messaging-people__message">
    <object></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. У вас возможно еще не правильно работают строчки

```
const objects = element.querySelectorAll('object');
const object = objects[objects.length - 1];
```

Потому что для элементов `.messaging-people__human`, `.messaging-people__message` находится один и тот же `object`.

Comment: Логика приложения в том, чтобы просто получить ноды svg изнутри object и записать ссылки на них в объект. Как я буду работать с ними дальше - это не важно. Если получать одну ноду через await, то все работает, а если несколько, то нет (срабатывает error timeout). Вот это для меня главная загадка, очень хочется понять причину.

Comment: Скорее всего события load выстреливают раньше, чем вешаются listener'ы на них. Пока скрипт ждет load от первого object, остальные уже выстреливают, и, при следующей итерации, он уже никогда не дождется этого события. Все как вы описали вначале сообщения.

Comment: @Janealter тут вы немножко не правы. Скрипт не ждет, когда загрузится первый `object`, он работает асинхронно. Но вы правы, на уже загруженном `object`(может быть взят из кеша - это быстро) событие `onload` не работает. Посему, попробуйте то что я предложил - *Возможно, можно проверить если object уже загружен, получить `object.contentDocument.querySelector('svg')` и если он есть, то потом уже выполнять resolve*

Comment: @Janealter я обновил ответ. Теперь проверяется на уже загруженный `object` и симулируется успешная загрузка у других `object`.

Comment: @Kasyanenko Я ведь вызываю функцию через `await`, значит скрипт ждет, пока она выполнится асинхронно:

`await prepareElement(elements[0], 0);` - первый вызов, скрипт ожидает выполнения асинхронной функции, которая вешает листнер на `load` и выполняет что-то, когда `load` выстрелит.

`await prepareElement(elements[1], 1);`  - второй вызов, будет выполнен только после успешного/неуспешного результата первого.
Событие `load` у `object` из `elements[1]` уже выстрелит, пока ожидается ответ от первого `await`, поэтому в данном случае листнер не поймает его.

Comment: @Kasyanenko Поправьте, если я что-то не так понимаю, но вроде бы все логично.
Ведь `async/await` как раз придуманы для того, чтобы сделать работу с асинхронными вызовами похожей на работу с синхронными. Поэтому в конструкции с несколькими `await` получается, что второй ждет, пока выполнится первый, третий ждет, пока выполнится второй и т.д.

Comment: @Janealter Да, вы правы, не учел, что у вас в цикле тоже `await` стоит. Получилось решить проблему? Посмотрели мой ответ?